# Converting a String to a date object and return it

Tags: java, localdate

I am having a hard time getting my `getDate` method to work.  I am prompting the user to input a date style MM/dd/yyyy as a String.  I need to convert the string to a date object and return it.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

public static String getDate(String prompt) {
    String dateAsString = getString(prompt);
    do {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        dateAsString = keyboard.nextLine();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");
        LocalDate dateAsString1=formatter.parse(dateAsString1); 
    }
    while (dateAsString == null || dateAsString.length() < 1);

    return dateAsString; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: On this line         LocalDate dateAsString1=formatter.parse(dateAsString1);  I am receiving the error the method parse(CharSequence) in the type DateTimeFormatter is not applicalbe for the argument (LocalDate)

Comment: Well I see two protential problems with this. Firstly, you are trying to format the string using `M/dd/yyyy` instead of `MM/dd/yyyy` as you said in your question. Second problem is that before the `do-while` loop, you call a function called `getString` and assign the value to `dateAsString`, then inside the `do-while`, you also assign the value of `keyboard.nextLine()` to `dateAsString`.

Comment: Well, if you need to return a date object (I assume you mean a `LocalDate` object more precisely), then the return type of your method should not be `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Your current method does too many things. Simply pass in the `String` you want to convert to a `LocalDate` and use [`LocalDate.parse(CharSequence, DateTimeFormatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) to parse that `String` and return the result. Something like,

```
public static LocalDate parseDate(String str) {
    return LocalDate.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy"));
}
```

And to test it, I just did

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(parseDate("10/31/2021"));
}
```

Finally, I recommend clear and separate concerns for your methods. That way it's far easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) Does Not Have Any Method Called ".parse()". Only The [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) Have The "[.parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-)" method and we need to pass the `String` and `DateTimeFormatter` in that `parse()` function. And When The Given String Does Not Matches The Pattern It Will Throw An Error(`DateTimeParseException` ) ! So I Added Try And Catch Method

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");

try{  LocalDate dateAsString1 = LocalDate.parse(dateAsString,formatter);  }
catch(DateTimeParseException e){ 
    //Wrong String Formation
}
```

Comment: Well, according to your link `DateTimeFormatter` has got [a `parse` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-), or rather, three of them. Your suggestion is OK in any case.